# How to show a different column for linked has_many_association table in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have a table **Match** which has a has_many_association relationship to **Result**, in rails_admin the default is to put the **id** of the **Result** in the matches page. What I'd really like is the **player_id** displayed, but the link to be to the **id** so I can get a better idea of what happened in that match but still be able to click through to the result.

In short: how do you change the displayed column of related tables in rails_admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails_admin was not at fault here. I had my associations wrong. Once fixed rails admin picked up the names perfectly.